# is there any way to create a next app in nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

i want to create a nextjs 13 app, but when i write this command `npx create-next-app demo` it creates with nextjs v14 which i dont want, ive tried `npx create-next-app@13 demo` but still no success.
I cant find any help in documentation regarding this.

Comment: `npx create-next-app@13` is working fine for me. Installs `"next": "13.5.6"` from `create-next-app@13.5.6`. Maybe caching is the problem?

Comment: @mutil yup I installed it seperately and it worked fine, i used the ```npx create-next-app``` then deleted the next 14 and installed next 13 manually

Answer (score 1):

try installing the specific create-next-app release first

```bash
npm install -g create-next-app@13.5.6
```

then try creating the app

```bash
npx create-next-app demo
```

you can follow this [similar comment on github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35794#discussioncomment-4762089)

Comment: i used the ``npx create-next-app``` then deleted the next 14 and installed next 13 manually, it worked

Comment: it will always pull latest thats why, https://g.co/bard/share/1e1fe101d40f

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread. But I also needed to do this and only this worked for me.

```
npx create-next-app@13
```

This installed **"next": "13.5.6"** for me. Found the solution from here

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35794#discussioncomment-7763059